# How can I count a column with values

Tags: sql

I have a column in sql table which contains 3 different values; ef: present, absent and leave. I want to count them with select and return different counts which reperesent them. How can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select columnname, count(*)
from YourTable
group by columnName
```

or

```
select 
sum(case when columnname='present' then =1 end) 'present',
sum(case when columnname='absent' then =1 end) 'absent',
sum(case when columnname='leave' then =1 end) 'leave'
from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks, my select statement is: select count(*)
from sms.dbo.emp_attendance
where username = 'admin' AND attendance = 'present'
group by attendance

Comment: @Badar since you are grouping by attendance you might want to add this to your select statement as a column, or remove redundant group by.